# pandas parser error and return can not be calculated

Tags: pandas

I am trying to find the return for a stock and getting errors relate to "Key Error". Following is the code , I am using to calculate. Here, I am using yahoo finance to pull data related to stocks and trying to calculate return.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas_datareader
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2017,4,1)
end  =  datetime.datetime(2022,4,1)
ICICIBNK = web.DataReader('ICICIBANK.NS','yahoo',start,end)['Adj Close']
HDFCBNK =  web.DataReader('HDFCBANK.NS','yahoo',start,end)['Adj Close']
KOTAKBNK = web.DataReader('KOTAKBANK.NS','yahoo',start,end)['Adj Close']
AXISBNK =  web.DataReader ('AXISBANK.NS','yahoo',start,end)['Adj Close']

ICICIBNK
Date
2017-04-03    252.629593
2017-04-05    250.999496
2017-04-06    247.474792
2017-04-07    244.390732
2017-04-10    244.655090

for stock_df in (ICICIBNK,HDFCBNK,KOTAKBNK,AXISBNK):
    stock_df['Normal Return'] = stock_df['Adj Close'] /stock_df.iloc[0]['Adj Close']

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._convert_str_to_tsobject()



ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp


KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ALOKKU~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21656/1292708730.py in <module>
      1 for stock_df in (ICICIBNK,HDFCBNK,KOTAKBNK,AXISBNK):
----> 2     stock_df['Normal Return'] = stock_df['Adj Close'] /stock_df.iloc[0]['Adj Close']


KeyError: 'Adj Close'
```

Regards
Alok Beheria

Comment: I'll guess that `web.DataReader` does return a DF - but you're immediately doing `['Adj Close']` on it - so those 4 "DF"s are actually that single column and thus a `Series` object. Remove that from your four reads and go from there...

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I did remove the "Adj Close' column and I was able to make it work. Here, I am also trying to add another column to my data frame called "Allocation" . for which I am using following code.

Comment: for list , allo in zip ((ICICIBNK,HDFCBNK,KOTAKBNK,AXISBNK),[.3,.2,.4,.1]):
    stock_df['Allocation'] = stock_df['Normal Return']*allo .. Here , I only see Allocation value to AXISBNK and others only showing values till "Normal Return"